# In AndroidKernel.mk, what does "$(KERNEL_OUT):" mean?

Tags: android, c, makefile

In AndroidKernel.mk, what does "$(KERNEL_OUT):" mean?

in my code.

```
$(KERNEL_OUT):
     mkdir -p $(KERNEL_OUT)

$(KERNEL_CONFIG): | $(KERNEL_OUT)
     $(MAKE) -C kernel O=../$(KERNEL_OUT) ARCH=$(KERNEL_ARCH) 
CROSS_COMPILE=$(KERNEL_CROSS_COMPILE) $(KERNEL_DEFCONFIG)
```

what dose `$(KERNEL_OUT):` mean?

Especially, what is `:` ?

Does it mean:

```
if $(A): $(A) then
    execute below code
```

example:

```
$(A): $(A)
    $(info TEST)
```

result: `TEST`

Answer (score 0):

This is a [simple makefile rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction):

```
target … : prerequisites …
        recipe
        …
        …
```

> A `target` is usually the name of a file that is generated by a program;
>   examples of targets are executable or object files.
>
> A `prerequisite` is a file that is used as input to create the `target`.
>   A `target` often depends on several files.
>
> A `recipe` is an action that make carries out.

The `:` is the separation between the `target` and the `prerequisites`, and below the `recipes` to execute.

In [your example](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-7.1.1_r0.49/AndroidKernel.mk#79), `$(KERNEL_OUT)` refer to a variable previously defined:

```
KERNEL_OUT := $(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)/KERNEL_OBJ

...

$(KERNEL_OUT):
    mkdir -p $(KERNEL_OUT)
```

Moreover, the `$(TARGET_OUT_INTERMEDIATES)` is a variable defined in the [Android build system](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/envsetup.mk#387) which is something like: `out/target/product/your_target/obj`

---

To be more comprehensible:

- `$(KERNEL_OUT)` is the directory where all the kernel object will be stored
- Once extended it looks like: `out/target/product/your_target/obj`
- The rule to create it is a simple `mkdir`
- The `$(KERNEL_OUT)` can be used as a prerequisite of other rules to be sure that this directory is created before to run this rules.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer!!